# Javascript: should I remove an event handler when removing the related HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, unbind

I have the following HTML on a page:

```
<div class="component">
  <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
</div>
```

And I have the following script at page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a.delete').on('click', function() {
    ....
  });

});
```

This page has other Javascript code that manipulates the page and removes  via:

```
$('.component').remove();
```

My question: do I need to remove (unbind) the event handler before removing the HTML? If not, will there be any memory leak or other impact?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using jQuery, you don't need to worry about it.

> Similar to [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty), the `.remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM. Use `.remove()` when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, **all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.** To remove the elements without removing data and events, use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead.

http://api.jquery.com/remove/ (emphasis added)

Comment: Matt, what if I insert the removed component to a new place on the same page? Should I remove the event handler before insert? I know that I have to re-attach the event handler AFTER insert if I want the click handler to continue to work.

Comment: Please read carefully. The last sentence that I quoted addresses that.